# What's the difference between rendering and shaders?

Tags: shaders, rendering

What is rendering? What are shaders like vertex ,tessellation shaders etc? I am confused what's the difference between rendering and shaders? and how rendering is performed using shaders? Can we perform rendering without shaders? are shaders used in both films(like toy story) and games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rendering is a very generic term which is basically can be defined as "creating an image", which can be, obviously, created in many ways. For example if you fill memory with color values (software rendering) it is also a "rendering".

Shaders are completely other thing. They are related to how modern GPUs work. Say you want to render a triangle. You supply triangle coordinates to GPU. You also load a shader to GPU. Then GPU is rendering data you supplied, it is executing your shader on every triangle vertex (vertex shader) and every triangle pixel (pixel shader). In shader you basically transform coordinates (vertex) and change color (pixel) of your final image. That's VERY basic on what shaders are. Shaders are very powerful and very fast, most effects in modern games are possible because of shaders.

As [@tkausl](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/49789/tkausl) correctly mentioned, modern GPU pipeline actually requres shaders do draw anything. They are often hidden behind frameworks like, for example, XNA. They can be called "Identity" shaders, which only transform your "screen coordinates" to OpenGL or DirectX coordinates and do not modify pixels, except for handling transparency.

So to answer your questions:

> I am confused what's the difference between rendering and shaders?

They are not comparable.

> and how rendering is performed using shaders?

I guess I answered that above.

> Can we perform rendering without shaders?

Absolutely we can.

> are shaders used in both films(like toy story) and games?

Yes. Though I would guess they differ significantly since Pixar is not using your typical OpenGL or DirectX API, but the concept of "shader" should be the same. Also Pixar is not rendering in real-time, so they could use much more complex algorithms.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning, that you can not render without a Shader in *modern* OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering is the whole process of drawing something on the screen.

And this process consists of multiple steps. In a modern GPU based renderer this means basically and simplified:

- Uploading vertices of triangle-meshes to the GPU (done by the program running on the CPU)
- Positioning these vertices in the view-frustum of the screen. Typically by applying a model-view-projection matrix. (done by a vertex-shader)
- Assemble 3 vertices to a triangle (done by the GPU)
- Clipping = Throw away triangles, that are outside of the screen (done by the GPU)
- Optional: tesselation: cutting these triangles into multiple smaller triangles
  (Done by a tesselation- shader, a fixed tesselator and a geometry-shader)
- Rasterizing the remaining triangles = calculating, which fragments are covered by these triangles. There can be multiple fragments per pixel. And fragments have a depth component (done by the GPU)
- Throw away fragments, that are not visible (outside of the screen, or covered by other fragments) (done by the GPU)
- Calculating the color of each fragment. For example a phong-shader. (this is done by fragment-shaders)
- Combining colors of the fragments of each pixel (for anti aliasing, or transparency effects) (done by the GPU)
- Showing the final image on the screen

Some of these steps are executed by the application on the CPU. Some of these steps are executed by fixed circuits on the GPU, and some of these steps are executed by shaders, that run on the GPU.
These shaders are small programs, that are provided by the application (like a game). They are executed on the GPU.
On older GPUs without shaders, these steps are also performed by a fixed circuit on the GPU. But then they are not called shaders (so: rendering also works without shaders).

See more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Renderer executes the final image/as a whole, including its part, the shader. They are both mathematical in nature, coded into programs. This makes a shader a subset of a renderer.

A metaphor for this is, the 'shaders' are the visual effects people, in the scene in a movie but the director, the 'renderer', is responsible for the final look of a scene.

[as bitmapped image/images formed by logical pixels (coz' there are many more physical pixels in a pixel nowadays, like in Retina displays, there are subpixels even more divided into subpixels for the individual red, green & blue colors), also called rasterized image, which are images generated line by line, thus the refresh rates]